# Semi transparent MarkerImage in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a map with custom marker images.  The image I'm using is semi transparent.  When I display it in the map only a small triangle show in the bottom right of where is icon should be.

Can semitransparent images be used as imagemarkers in google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes transparent images can be used as custom marker images.  It's good practice to specify the size of the image when creating the image object e.g.

```
 var customMarkerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('image.png', new google.maps.Size(20, 20), null, new google.maps.Point(10, 10));
```

This may also resolve your problem with the image partially displaying.